# Date format mm/dd/yyyy not converting to dd.mm.yyyy

Tags: date, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script used to merge different excel-dumps of credit card and bank account monthly lists into one and sorted by date.
I have to add a new credit card now, and the excel-dumps I get there has a date value that differs from the other ones I've already solved in my script. So I have ran into problems converting data to the common format dd.mm.yyyy .

New problematic date values: MM/DD/YYYY

**11/09/2022 converts to: 11.09.2022** (which is still wrong. Should be 09.11.2022),

**11/21/2022 does not convert at all**
etc

I tried to use the existing code I use for the other date formats to get it into the correct format. While it seems to work as long as the day value (DD) is below 12, it doesn't do anything to the date value if the day value is above 12. Which suggests I can't use my present code for this conversion.

Current code:

```
  spreadsheet.getRange('A:A').activate();
  spreadsheet.setCurrentCell(spreadsheet.getRange('A52'));
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setNumberFormat('dd.MM.yyyy');
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
```

I even tried switching dd.MM.yyyy to MM.dd.yyyy as a dirty quick fix. But this didn't help for the ones it didn't want to convert. It only switched dd and MM for the dates it DID convert.
Result:

**11/09/2022 converts to: 09.11.2022** (which is correct),

**11/21/2022 does not convert at all**
etc

Any suggestions? Is there a way to do this in a similar command as I already use, or do I need to do 2 steps bringing the date to another format before doing my normal conversion?

Comment: Are the inputs date objects or strings?  If strings then you may have to split them up yourself.  If data objects then create new Date() and use Utilities.formatDate().

Comment: How do I find out if they're objects or strings? I would assume strings. The file is just an Excel-dump of credit card statements from credit card provider.

Comment: Actually I think they're not strings since some of the dates convert correctly (the ones which has a value less than 12 in the middle number, which would indicate that the problem is a MM & DD converting problem).

Comment: If it's a Date() object then you could use range.setNumberFormat() on it to simply change the display format.

Comment: problem seems to be it's assuming it's reading DD/MM/YYYY while it's actually reading MM/DD/YYYY. So when the middle number exceeds 12 it's not converting.
Tried switching DD & MM in the setNumberFormat, but the only outcome was that the onesit converted was switched. The ones with higher number than 12 in the middle part were unchanged.

Comment: Here's an example file describing my source file, what I want & what I get now.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z15QVzcvFb6YWCxMpdgzulKC6OQ-VW64CSJHp6Z5_20/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Suggestion:

Try using getRange() or getActiveRange() instead.

### For getActiveRange():

```
function setDateFormat() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  ss.getActiveRange().setNumberFormat('dd.MM.yyyy');
}
```

### Output:

Select the desired data to be converted:

[image]

After running the script:

[image]

### For getRange():

No need to select the data, just input the range:

```
function setDateFormat() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  ss.getRange("A1:A10").setNumberFormat('dd.MM.yyyy'); //change this range
}
```

### Output

[image]

After running the script:

The same output is to be expected.

[image]

### Update:

Upon viewing your sample spreadsheet, I found out that the data being read are in string form. You will need to first convert the string values into date format using `new Date()`. The updated script should look like this:

```
function setDateFormat() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var values = ss.getRange("A2:A58").getValues().map(x=>[new Date(x)]);
  ss.getRange("A2:A58").setValues(values).setNumberFormat('dd.MM.yyyy');
}
```

### Reference:

- [setNumberFormat()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnumberformatnumberformat)
- [getActiveRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactiverange)
- [getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation)
- [new Date()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp)
- [map()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp)

Comment: Please feel free to ask anything related to the posted answer.

Comment: Can't make it work. Seems that the input is not accepted since the mid-part of the date is assumed to be MM but is in fact DD. So when number exceeds 12 it doesn't convert.

Comment: That is rather unfortunate because it works on my side. Can you please share a sample spreadsheet which shows that the method does not work so that we may further look into it.

Comment: Here's an example file describing my source file, what I want & what I get now.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z15QVzcvFb6YWCxMpdgzulKC6OQ-VW64CSJHp6Z5_20/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for sharing a sample spreadsheet. I have added an update to the posted answer. I hope this fixes the issue at hand. Again, feel free to ask anything related to the posted answer.

Comment: Seems to be working. Late feedback because I've been pulling my hair trying to figure out why I got a syntax error in this line:


var values = ss.getRange("A2:A58").getValues().map(x=>[new Date(x)]);


Turns out I had to enable Chrome v8 in the settings of the project. It's an older script so this wasn't enabled before. The arrow sign needs Chrome v8 apparently.

Comment: It is good to hear that the method works. Also, thanks for sharing the details about `Turns out I had to enable Chrome v8 in the settings of the project.... The arrow sign needs Chrome v8 apparently.` I will take note of this for future reference.

Comment: Anyway, you may click the accept button (check icon) on the left if this solution fixed your issue. [how to accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: I accepted it. Tried to use the useful answers as well, but it seems I'm not qualified yet :-(
Many thanks though! After a lot of hairpulling I can finally progress.